# powershell foreach loop using a MYSQL query

Tags: mysql, powershell

I'm trying to pull a query from Mysql and get a loop from each entry of that query.

Here's the MySQL query:

`SELECT ad_groups FROM ad_test_table where ad_names = 'test'`

which returns

`test1,test2,test3`

now i want to do a for loop for each entry ad_group but it wont loop each of those separated by a coma

```
foreach ($group in $AD_query){
    write-host "group : " $group
}
```

which only loops once and gives me `test1,test2,test3`

Here's the full code. Is it the data that was incorrectly entered in the database or am I missing something in the code?

```
function mysql_query($query)
{
  $MySQLAdminUserName = 'AD_user'
  $MySQLAdminPassword = 'AD_password'
  $MySQLDatabase = 'User_creation'
  $MySQLHost = 'AD_MySQL_server'
  $ConnectionString = "server=" + $MySQLHost + ";port=3306;uid=" + 
  $MySQLAdminUserName + ";pwd=" + $MySQLAdminPassword + ";database="+$MySQLDatabase
  Try {
    [void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("MySql.Data")
    $Connection = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection
    $Connection.ConnectionString = $ConnectionString
    $Connection.Open()
    $Command = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand($Query, $Connection)
    $DataAdapter = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataAdapter($Command)
    $DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
    $RecordCount = $dataAdapter.Fill($dataSet, "data")
    $DataSet.Tables[0]
  }
  Catch {
    Write-Host "ERROR : Unable to run query : $query `n$Error[0]"
  }
  Finally {
    $Connection.Close()
  }
}




#$Full_AD_rights_list_query_full = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList

$AD_query = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
$AD_query = mysql_query "SELECT ad_groups FROM ad_test_table where ad_names = 'test'"


foreach ($group in $AD_query.item(0)) {
  write-host ""
  write-host "group : " $group
}
```

Comment: 1st - what do you get from `AD_Query.GetType()`? ///// [2] what does `$DataSet.Tables[0]` contain while in your function? ///// i ask because it LOOKS like you are returning a string, not an array.

Answer (score 0):

mysql_query return a datatable. Your result is a datatable (not aSystem.Collections.ArrayList because overwrite) . Try this:

```
foreach ($Row in $AD_query.Rows)
{ 
  "value is : {0}" -f $Row["ad_groups"]
}
```